# Remove multiple occurrences of a string regex on a file, line by line

Tags: regex, perl, regex-negation

I have a file test.txt:

```
12-09:30:09:802775 |539----> 116 Bl_LE 502450553  |  <D BeginString="FIX.4.2"  (...) LTPrice="13.21" 9999="bar" CheckSum="145" 12345="xxx"></D>
12-09:30:09:802775 |539----> 116 Bl_LE 502450553  |  <D BeginString="FIX.4.2"  (...) LTPrice="13.21" 1010="foo" CheckSum="145" 65464="xxx"></D>
```

I'm trying to remove all the key/pairs that are starting with a number (9999="bar",1010="foo",etc.) to have the final lines like this:

```
12-09:30:09:802775 |539----> 116 Bl_LE 502450553  |  <D BeginString="FIX.4.2"  (...) LTPrice="13.21" CheckSum="145"></D>
12-09:30:09:802775 |539----> 116 Bl_LE 502450553  |  <D BeginString="FIX.4.2"  (...) LTPrice="13.21" CheckSum="145"></D>
```

I was trying to use a one-liner with the "tr" command, but can't figure out how to put this together:

```
$$ perl -ne 'tr/(\d+="[^"]*")//g' test.txt
Bareword found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "tr/(\d+="[^"]*")//g"
syntax error at -e line 1, next token ???
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Any ideas about how I can achieve this?

Comment: `tr///` is for mapping individual character replacements.  As the answer below demonstrates, you want `s///` to use a regular expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use:

```sh
perl -pe 's/\h+\d+="[^"]*"//g' test.txt

12-09:30:09:802775 |539----> 116 Bl_LE 502450553  |  <D BeginString="FIX.4.2"  (...) LTPrice="13.21" CheckSum="145"></D>
12-09:30:09:802775 |539----> 116 Bl_LE 502450553  |  <D BeginString="FIX.4.2"  (...) LTPrice="13.21" CheckSum="145"></D>
```

**RexEx Details:**

- `\h+`: Match 1 or more whitespaces
- `\d+`: Match 1+ digits
- `=`: Match a `=`
- `"[^"]*"`: Match a quoted value